# Лучшее время для задавания вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, ответы, статистика, data-explorer

Иногда я задаю вопрос, и там около просмотра каждую минуту. И ответ приходит поздно. А иногда задаю, и сразу идут ответы. Я не могу определить лучшее время, чтобы задать вопрос и сразу получить ответ. Нужно попасть в золотую середину, когда с одной стороны России активность, и с другой стороны тоже.

Время предлагаю опубликовать Московское.

Comment: related: [What is the best time to ask questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/what-is-the-best-time-to-ask-questions)

Comment: @jfs Я бы так не сказал, там же время английского SO, а здесь русский.

Comment: посмотрите что слово "related" означает. Или вы хотите сказать что никак вопросы не связаны?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Можно, к примеру, посмотреть этот вопрос: [Question and answer activity on Stack Exchange: Interactive and customized edition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213603/260198).

Всё зависит от того, какую метрику оценивать. К примеру, если мы говорим о скорости получения ответа, то можно [вот такой запрос](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/901647/stack-overflow----?All=1&Frequency=1&MaxTimeDiff=1440&UserId=15479#graph) использовать.

Если `All = 1` (для всех пользователей) и по тому, в каком часу дан ответ `Frequency = 1`, то такой график:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что быстрее ответы получают вопросы заданные в районе 6-12 часов по UTC (9-15 часов по Москве).

Если посмотреть по дням недели `Frequency = 3`, то:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 <sup>*на графике 1 - это воскресенье</sup>

Если я ничего не путаю, то:

1. Выгодно задавать в рабочее время по Москве (9-15 часов).
2. В будние дни отвечают быстрее.

Comment: Забавное наблюдение: самое неудачное для вопрошающих время — ночь с понедельник на вторник.

Comment: @Arhad отходят от первого рабочего дня :D